# Is it possible to get the data type of the complex field of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, ienumerable

Issue : When the filtering operation is performed based on the complex filed to the DataSource, Error has been thrown

Requirement : Need to get the Data type of the complex field attribute So that i can do the filtering operation on that Data Source.

I have defined my performFiltering Method as follows and it has two arguments

First argument : DataSource As IEnumerable
Second argument : FilteredColumn as List

DataSource Holds the following data,

```
Order
{
  OrderID : Long
  EmployeeID : String
  Employee : Info
}

Info
{
     Address : String
}
```

and the "FilteredColumn" holds the following data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgxQo.png)

In this above pic, Field is set as Employee.Address, So i need to filter the Order DataBase Based on the Address Field.

How to get the Data Type of Address which is present inside in the Info class.

I have tried with the following way

```
        string[] splits = filteredColumn.Field.Split('.');
        var prop = dataSource.AsQueryable().ElementType.GetProperties();
        Type type = null;
        object value = null;
        foreach (var pro in prop)
        {
            if (splits.Length == 1)
            {
                if (pro.Name == filteredColumn.Field)
                    type = pro.PropertyType;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string split in splits)
                {
                    if(pro.Name == split)
                        type = pro.PropertyType;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I cannot able to get the Address data Type.

Could you please figure out my mistake in the above code block.